# When load svg format pic has some error

Tags: android, svg, crash

I have error when load svg format photo :

```
No static method buildStreamModelLoader(Ljava/lang/Class;Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/bumptech/glide/load/model/ModelLoader; in class Lcom/bumptech/glide/Glide; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.bumptech.glide.Glide' appears in /data/app/ir.vian_web.pezeshkyab-lCn-nMRSyq-17dH9hkz8bA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
```

I used lib SvgLoader :

```
     @Override
      public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Cats cats = list.get(position);
        holder.txt_title.setText(cats.getTitle()); 
        SvgLoader.pluck().with((Activity) context).load(cats.getImage(),holder.image);
```

and my gradle :

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ir.vian_web.pezeshkyab"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0")` will resolve the issue.